# Copy and Paste VBA Syntax Error (Error 400)

Tags: excel, vba

My excel workbook contains a "Raw Data" sheet with a macro-assigned button. I want to parse the data in that sheet into corresponding sheets that has accompanying graphs in them after pressing the button. Below is the code that I am working on:

```
Public maxVoltage As Long
Public rowCount As Long

Sub RunAllMacros()
    getData
    parseData
End Sub

Sub getData()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    maxVoltage = InputBox("Input nominal voltage (V).")

    Range("B2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    rowCount = Selection.Count + 1

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub parseData()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Worksheets("Raw Data").Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(rowCount, 2)).Copy _
        Destination:=Worksheets("Voltage and Current").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(rowCount, 1))

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The getData() function is used to count the number of rows in the "Raw Data" sheet because the number of data may vary. The data will start in Column B with the top row serving as headings or names for the data. So the data will start in the 2nd row. My problem is that the syntax I use to copy and paste the data from the "Raw Data" sheet to the "Voltage and Current" sheet gives me Error 400. I do not know if this syntax does not accept variables as arguments in the 'Range' object. I will appreciate any help.

Comment: You need to fully qualify all your calls to `Cells` and `Range` with the worksheet they're referring to instead of using the globals.

Comment: What do you mean fully qualify my calls? Do I need to explicitly activate the corresponding worksheets before I am able to parse the data from one sheet to another?

Comment: No, you need to add the worksheet.  I.e. `Worksheets("Raw Data").Range(Worksheets("Raw Data").Cells(2, 2), Worksheets("Raw Data").Cells(RowCount, 2)).Copy`

Comment: try `Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("B2:B" & rowCount).Copy _
        Destination:=Worksheets("Voltage and Current").Range("A2")`

Comment: Thanks Comintern! That solution worked well. Thank you too nightcrawler23. Have a nice day!